# How to parse the values from this JSON response in Swift 3?

Tags: json, parsing, swift3

This is the JSON response, that I receive from the server. I tried to parse the values without any success.

```
{"items":
   [{"item":
     {  "id":824,
        "company_id":31,
        "config_id":45,
        "imagesmall":null,
        "imagethumb":null,
        "pointofsales":null,
        "status":true,
        "endPlanned":false
      }
   },
   {"item":
    {   "id":889,
        "company_id":74,
        .
        .
        .
        "status":true,
        "endPlanned":false
    }
  }]
}
```

Code I'm trying

```
if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any]{ 
    print(json) // does work 
    let item = json?["items"] as? [[String: Any]] 
    print(item?[0]) // does work 
    // ... from here I am looking for the code to access the values and print it out ... 
}
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: Not here [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42000176/edit) with your try code and what is not working with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print `item` you need to loop through the `items` array.

```
if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String: Any],
   let items = json["items"] as? [[Strin:Any]] {

     for item in items {
         if let dic = item["item"] as? [String:Any] {
             print(dic["id"])
             print(dic["company_id"])
             print(dic["config_id"])
             //and so on..
         }
     }
}
```

**Note:** With Swift native type there is no need to specify the options with (de)serialization.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Looks so easy.... I just started with swift trying to overcome the issues by my own, but sometimes I just stuck:-)

Comment: @Jim Welcome mate :)